# Употребление слова «авторесса»

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

> *Авторесса Мегуми Кишида. Тканый зонт.*

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста,можно ли употреблять слово «авторесса» в русском языке, применительно к автору женского рода? Существует ли оно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В серьезном тексте его лучше не употреблять, нормативными словарями оно не фиксируется, а как разговорное обычно снабжается пометой "шутл." ибо даже в обычном, бытовом контексте звучит иронически и даже уничижительно.

Менее  выражено - "авторша", но и оно не для серьезных текстов, тоже ироническое, хотя и не так уничижительно.

Вообще в русском языке названия профессий и должностей специальных женских форм обычно не имеют.

Подробнее - [здесь](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/363/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%82.%D0%B4.)

Answer (score 1):

Авторе́сса приводится в [орфографическом словаре](http://orfo.ruslang.ru/abc/part?start=603&end=903) Института русского языка им. Виноградова.

Comment: Вопрос был в том, можно ли употреблять слово, а не где оно приводится. Это первое. Второе, вы "забыли" упомянуть что данный электронный словарь разрабатывается не ИРЯ Виноградова, а всего лишь сайтом "АКАДЕМОС" имеющим весьма крсвенное отношениея к ИРЯ.

Comment: Ответ подтверждает, что слово существует. Было бы несколько странно думать, что какое-то слово существует в русском языке, но не может в нём употребляться. Приведенный ресурс ссылается на словарь Лопатина и несложно проверить, что там это слово есть.

Comment: [Здесь](http://orfo.ruslang.ru/) подробнее о легитимности словаря.

Answer (score 0):

Почему шутливое и пренебрежительное? Неужели "авторка" лучше?! По-моему, очень даже уважительное, даже тяжеловесное. Сравните: ветреный поэт и благородная поэтесса. Так и тут: небрежный автор и заботящаяся о читателях авторесса (авторисса).

Директор и директриса. Пилот и пилотесса. Мотор и (авто)мотриса (техн.). Моторист и моторисса. Некоторые профессии для женщин, появившиеся и разрешённые недавно, иначе вообще нельзя образовать: машинист и машинисса. Не машинистка же!

Через -есса не образуются непроизносимые слова: например, крановесса, кранесса звучат просто дико и непонятно в сравнении с нормальным крановщица. Но авторщица же не скажешь!

Так что да здравствуют авторессы и авториссы.

Comment: * авториса,  моториса,  машиниса - http://virgoclub.ru/feminitivy-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke.html ;  аббатиса, диакониса, директриса, инспектриса, лектриса - https://kot-kam.livejournal.com/1707109.html

Comment: *Почему шутливое и пренебрежительное?* Потому что несет в себе признак сексизма. Женщину-автор следует называть автором. 
А сравнение с поэтессой здесь весбма спорное. Не говоря уж о том, что сами поэты эту "поэтессу" терпеть не могут.  ***Моим стихам, написанным так рано, // Что и не знала я, что я — поэт, "*** (Марина Цветаева)

Comment: @Galina Avanesova В наших храмах женщин как служителей нет, и это вопрос решённый. Все жёны клира матушками зовутся.

Comment: Я-то давала коммент на тему суффикса *-ис-...*